# Preventing a block's custom template file from being cached

Tags: theming, blocks, caching

I have built a module that needs to provide a small piece of dynamic content on every page load of a certain content type. It works great, however the section of code I provided is always cached in Drupal theme registry (it seems). The Variables I need generated on each pageload are "$userpicturepath" and "$variables['userfullname']" How do I prevent this from being cached? For completeness, here is my module's code:

*subscribe_blocks.module*

```
//implementation of hook_block_info
function subscribe_blocks_block_info() {    
    $blocks['author_subscribe_block'] = array(
        'info' => t('Author Subscribe Block'),
        'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
    );
    return $blocks;
}

//implementation of hook_block_view
function subscribe_blocks_block_view($delta = '') {
    switch ($delta) {
        case 'author_subscribe_block':
            $blocks['content'] = theme('subscribe_blocks_block');
            break;
    }
    return $blocks;
}


// Implementation of hook_theme
function subscribe_blocks_theme(){
    if ( arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) ) {
        $node = node_load(arg(1));
    }
    $user_fields = user_load($node->uid);

    return array(
        'subscribe_blocks_block' => array(
            'template' => 'subscribeblocks',
            'variables' => array( 
                'userfullname' => $user_fields->field_name['und'][0]['safe_value'],
                'userpicture' => $user_fields->picture->filename,
                'userfields' => $user_fields,
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

*subscribeblocks.tpl.php*

```
<?php
drupal_page_is_cacheable(FALSE);

if ($variables['userpicture'] != NULL){
    $userpicturepath = 'sites/example.com/files/styles/user_profile/public/pictures/' . $variables['userpicture']; 
} else{
    $userpicturepath = 'https://someimgurl';
}
?>

<div class='subscribe-bar'>
    <div class='container'>
        <div class='col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-2'>
            <div class='subscribe-left'>
                <img src=<?php echo $userpicturepath; ?> class='subscribeuserpic' >
            </div>
            <div class='subscribe-right'>
                <p>Never miss another story by <strong><?php echo($variables['userfullname']); ?></strong>. Subscribe today.</p>
                <div class='slideInFormContainer'>
                    <?php
                    $block = module_invoke('webform', 'block_view', 'client-block-5401');
                    print render($block['content']);
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using Drupal 7, have all other caching turned off (for now), and have tried using several modules including CacheExclude (https://www.drupal.org/project/cacheexclude) and Ajax Blocks (https://www.drupal.org/project/ajaxblocks).

Comment: `however the section of code I provided is always cached` which section? based on the code's comments you provided above, I cannot tell.

Comment: Good point, the cached items are $userpicturepath and $variables['userfullname']

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best way to do this, but I was able to overcome this by rebuilding the theme cache when this block was run using:

```
<?php
drupal_theme_rebuild();
```

I'd love if someone could help with a better answer though!